# CSS 3 animation not executing the first time it is called

Tags: javascript, html, css

So... I have this small webpage with two divs, a button, two css classes and a function in javascript.

The idea is that when pressing the button, the function changes the css class of the div and hides it with a nice transition. When pressing it again, it does the opossite:

The HTML:

```
<div id="div1" >
  <div id="div2" >
    Here be HTML stuffs.
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
hideNShow(){

  var w = $('#div2');
  var height = w.outerHeight();    

  if(document.getElementById("div1").className=="hidden")
      document.getElementById("div1").className="visible";
      document.getElementById("div1").style.height=height + "px";
  } else if (document.getElementById("div1").className=="visible") {
      document.getElementById("div1").className="hidden";
      document.getElementById("div1").style.height=0 + "px";
  }
}
```

And the CSS classes:

```
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease; 
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

The button is just a button with the function referenced in a different div.

My problem, right now is that if div1 has "hidden" as starting class (), it works just fine (all the transitions works as intended with the intended delay), but if the starting class is "visible", the first time I press the button, the div hides automatically, ignoring the transition.

I've looked around and found nothing. It seems that the first

EDIT: Fixed a typo on the code with a name for a div.

Comment: You seem to be missing the correct `id` in this line `document.getElementById("div").style.height=height + "px";` as it cannot find an element with `id=div`

Comment: You use jQuery for div2, but plain JS selecting for div1. That's funny :)

Comment: you should have  some default height. add `height: auto` to `visible` class and check. And also it seems you are not having any class by default..

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: Typo when copying the code, sorry!

Comment: @Anarion: Got to say I inherited most of this code from other developer and I'm messing around with small changes so... yeah, anything can happen here..

Comment: @Mr_Green: It seems that the part in which i wrote about having the starting class set to "visible" in div1 got lost. Also, tried the auto value (which seems to be [the default value for the property] (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) and didn't work.

Comment: @Neuromante the transition will work if you provide any value by default. try some other fixed value just for testing and check..

Comment: @Mr_Green: True! I forgot about it. It is working now (badly, as I put a wrong number, but all I have to do is ask for the size of the container in the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing visiblity:hidden and visiblity:visible

Answer (score 1):

Foremost, the condition **if ... className=='visible'; else if ... className=='hidden'** is non-working, because #div1 don't have any of these classes.

But in any case the first turn of animation will not work (element will disappear immediately). The reason is that you have to explicitly set the height of #div1 before applying .hidden class to it which is resetting height to 0, while transition works only if element has CSS-parameter changed.

There is also a problem when setting height on click, immediately before adding .hidden class - it will not be transitioned again. This one is alike the problem described in the third paragraph [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Which_CSS_properties_are_animatable.3F).

```js
function init () {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    div1.style.height = div1.clientHeight + 'px';
    
    function hideNShow(){      
        if (div1.className.split(' ').indexOf('hidden') < 0) {
            div1.className += ' hidden';
        }
        else {
            div1.className = div1.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)hidden(?!\S)/g , '');
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', hideNShow);
}
init();
```

```css
.smooth {
    transition: all 1s ease; 
}

/*.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease; 
}*/

.hidden {
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    height: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*transition: all 1s ease;*/
}
```

```html
<button id="switch" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Switch</button>

<div id="div1" class="smooth" style="background:#F9E6C1;">
  <div id="div2" >
    Here be HTML stuffs.
  </div>
</div>
```